# mysql query for multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

mysql tables are as follows

```
    +------------+----------------+----------------+
    | booking_id | boarding_point | dropping_point |
    +------------+----------------+----------------+
    |          1 |              2 |              4 |
    |          2 |              1 |              2 |
    +------------+----------------+----------------+
```

```
    +-------------+---------------+
    | location_id | location_name |
    +-------------+---------------+
    |           1 | chennai       |
    |           2 | coimbatore    |
    |           3 | tiruppur      |
    |           4 | erode         |
    |           5 | salem         |
    +-------------+---------------+
```

boarding_point and dropping_point are foreign keys for location_id.
Now I want the select query to display like

```
    +------------+----------------+----------------+
    | booking_id | boarding_point | dropping_point |
    +------------+----------------+----------------+
    |          1 |     coimbatore |          erode |
    |          2 |        chennai |     coimbatore |
    +------------+----------------+----------------+
```

can anyone please suggest me the query to display like above.

Comment: You will want to `JOIN` the tables: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the booking table twice to the location table:

```
SELECT
    b.booking_id,
    t1.location_name,
    t2.location_name
FROM booking b
INNER JOIN location t1
    ON b.boarding_point = t1.location_id
INNER JOIN location t2
    ON b.dropping_point = t2.location_id;
```

[image]

### Demo